# Gravity forms / Recaptcha / Autoptimize - somewhere it goes wrong

Tags: cache, plugin-gravity-forms, google, captcha

I am using Gravity Forms and have recently started using their Google Captcha integration. (We also use Autoptimize )

The problem I have is that de captcha validation goes wrong, but I am not sure where to look for the solution.

My question is: how can I get this to work?

(Autoptimize: We already have the "aggregate inline JS" turned off)

We also have expiry clauses in our htaccess.
ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 2 months"
ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

Is anyone having the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

In Autoptimize, in the Javascript Options, there's a field to 'Exclude scripts from Autoptimize', you will add a script to the field.  You will need to add a comma to the last script already in the field then add this after:

`/recaptcha/api.js`

Hopefully, this helps.

Best,
Carm